# What is the best way to compare dates in Perl?

Tags: perl

I need to read 2 dates and compare them.

One date is the current_date (year,month,date)
the other is determined by the business logic.
I then need to compare the 2 dates and see if one is before the other.

How can I do the same in Perl?

I am searching for good documentation, but I am finding so many Date modules in Perl. Don't know which one is appropriate for it.

Comment: You might be interested in this [stack-exchange proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review"). It's almost ready to begin beta, just needs a few more.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

One of the most popular date modules is [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) which will handle all of the corner cases and other issues surrounding date math.

This link is a FAQ for DateTime which may help you get started:

- http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/page/FAQ

The way the `DateTime` module works is that you convert your dates (which will presumably be strings) into `DateTime` objects, which you can then compare using one of several `DateTime` methods.

In the examples below, `$dt1` and `$dt2` are `DateTime` objects.

`$days` is the delta between the two dates:

```
my $days = $dt1->delta_days($dt2)->delta_days;
```

`$cmp` is -1, 0 or 1, depending on whether `$dt1` is less than, equal to, or more than `$dt2`.

```
my $cmp = DateTime->compare($dt1, $dt2);
```

Comment: One of the many nice things about DateTime is it has full operator overloading -- e.g. you can compare two DateTime objects as `if ($dt1 < $dt2) { ... }`

Answer (score 38):

If the dates are [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) (ie, YYYY-MM-DD) and you do not need to validate them, you can compare lexicographically (ie, the `lt` and `gt` operators.)

If you need to validate the dates, manipulate the dates, or parse non standard formats -- use a CPAN module. The best, IMHO, are [DateTime](https://metacpan.org/pod/DateTime) and [DateCalc](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Calc). [Date-Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date::Simple) is pretty good too.

A good place to start on your own journey is to read [The Many Dates of Perl](http://www.perl.com/pub/2003/03/13/datetime.html) and the [DateTime site](http://datetime.perl.org/wiki/datetime/dashboard).

Answer (score 3):

[Date::Manip](https://metacpan.org/pod/Date%3a%3aManip) is a very good module for that.