# Regular expression to match credit card expiration date

Tags: regex

I have the following pattern which I'm trying to use to match credit card expiration dates:

```
(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?(([0-9]{4})|[0-9]{2}$)
```

and I'm testing on the following strings:

```
02/13
0213
022013
02/2013
02/203
02/2
02/20322
```

It should only match the first four strings, and the last 3 should not be a match as they are invalid. However the current pattern is also matching the last string. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe I'm just a little confused but are you sure your parenthesis are correct around the `[0-9]{4}` area?

Comment: @BlackVegetable I'm new to regex - what's the problem with the parentheses?

Comment: @moby See my answer below.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You're missing start of line anchor `^` and parenthesis are unmatched.

This should work:

```
re = /^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$/;
```

OR using word boundaries:

```
re = /\b(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})\b/;
```

#### Working Demo: http://regex101.com/r/gN5wH2

Comment: He/she might *not* want the starting anchor in his/her regex though.

Comment: Crazy! Why did the anchor change things?

Comment: @BlackVegetable: See working demo and play with regex there. I have created a demo for you to understand better with color coding: http://regex101.com/r/oN1uO1 Basically optional `/` make it match last 4 digits without anchor `^`

Comment: Ah, that is subtle.  On a related note, that tester is amazing.

Answer (score 3):

Since we're talking about a **credit card expiration date**, once you have validated the input date string using one of the fine **regex** expressions in the other answers, you'll certainly want to confirm that **the date is not in the past**.

To do so:

1. Express your input date string as `YYYYMM`. For example: **`201409`**
2. Do the same for the current date. For example: **`201312`**
3. Then simply [compare the date strings **lexicographically**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4199593/1497596): For example: **`201409 ge 201312`**.

In Perl, `ge` is the [greater than or equal to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175418/1497596) string comparison operator. Note that as [@Dan Cowell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1766809/dan-cowell) advised, credit cards typically expire on the last day of the expiry month, so it would be inappropriate to use the `gt` (greater than) operator.

Alternatively, if your language doesn't support comparing strings in this fashion, convert both strings to integers and instead do an arithmetic comparison.

Answer (score 1):

Move a right paran:

```
^(0[1-9]|1[0-2])\/?(([0-9]{4}|[0-9]{2})$)
```

The end anchor wasn't being applied to the [0-9]{4} option, so more numbers were allowed.

Comment: This still matches the last string.

Comment: I see it matches the end of the last string (not the whole thing). Add the start of line anchor to fix that. See edit.